# How git verifies passwords when switching branches

Tags: git

I want to do a certain logical verification when git switches branches, such as password verification, when I enter the password successfully, I can switch to the corresponding branch, when I enter the wrong password, I can't switch to the corresponding branch, I want to ask if there is any way to tie it, I tried the post-checkout git hooks, but it seems to be password verification after switching branches, and you can also switch branches when your password is wrong.

I've tried the post-checkout git hooks, but it seems to be password verified after switching branches, and you can also switch branches when you have a wrong password.

What I'm expecting is that when I run the git checkout command, I need to verify my password, and if I enter the correct password, I can successfully switch branches<branch_name>, and if I enter the wrong password, I can't switch branches.

Comment: There is no hook that runs before checkout, and even if there was, the user could just remove it (or not install it in the first place).

Comment: Why? Honestly: what's the goal? To be able to interact with a git repository you already need pretty much full access to it. If you such a hook were possible, it would be incredibly easy to remove/disable/ignore. The equivalent to `--no-verify` for `git commit` would disable it. Are you trying to avoid *accidental* switching or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If this is meant to keep certain people out of certain parts of the repo, then that is not possible. Reads are not granular in Git, so anyone who can read one part of the repo can read the entire thing.